# How do warlocks deal with the Healing Elixir spell, since their spell slots get higher-level as they level up?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, unearthed-arcana, spell-slots

How do warlocks deal with the *healing elixir* spell from [Unearthed Arcana: Starter Spells](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA-Starter-Spells.pdf), since it's a level 1 spell and warlocks use higher-level spell slots as they level up?

Answer (score 15):

Same as everyone else: they use a higher level slot, but don't gain anything beyond the 1st level effects.

> When a character casts a spell, he or she expends a slot of that spell's level **or higher**, effectively "filling" a slot with the spell.

You can find this in the PHB, page 201, under "spell slots". Emphasis mine.

Comment: Is it too broken to Home Brew the spell to have an additional d4 per slot level used? It's paralytically half the Cure Wounds Spell and you have either drink or administer it.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver I think that should be a separate question.

Comment: will do........